# YA book written between 2009 and 2012 - Orphaned girl is at school for people with magic. She has electricity powers

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

This book was about a girl whose family died in a car crash and she was the last survivor. She was at a school and she did not realize everyone had magical powers including herself. She’s this super powerful person that is meant to save everyone. The cover was blue and she had the power of electricity.

Comment: Was this a standalone book or a series?

Comment: [Evermore](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3975774-evermore)?

Comment: Evermore matches in a lot of ways. Ever's family is killed in a car crash, the cover is blue (ish) and it was written in 2009. But Ever doesn't have electrical powers.

Comment: It was a part of a series

Comment: @Elva De La Torre - Do you recall roughly how many books there were in the series? And how many you read? Also, did the girl have her powers in the first book, or develop them later?

Comment: She had them in the first book and I can’t remember how many were in the series but I read the first two

Comment: @ElvaDeLaTorre Did you have a look at [Evermore](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42009-the-immortals)? Is it the book you remember?